# PHP: shell_exec output max length

Tags: php, shell

I am trying to invoke a jar file from PHP code (with shell_exec() function) and it returns me only a part of the output buffer. I know it because if I invoke the same command from command line and I get a result with more characters.

Through PHP, I get only a string of 1024 chars.

My PHP's server is running on ubuntu.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: I think that the problem is not the shell execution, because now I'm storing the value in a file, and I'm putting it into a variable and it's not storing the complete value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    shell_exec("java -jar ".APP_PATH."framework/security/special_encryption.jar ".$filePath." E 2>&1")

May be some blank lines are breaking the output.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but, unfortunately, the output is the same. I think that the problem is the length of the output, because in all the cases, I get only the first 1024 characters.